# PowerShell script calling a TSQL query result

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with a PowerShell script calling a TSQL query result. I want the result of my SQL query to be assigned to the $Output variable as a single value, not a dataset. From my PowerShell script below the $Output variable returns…

```
$Output

Column1
--------
100
```

When I need the result to return a single value like the following…

```
$Output
100
```

Below is the PowerShell script I am using:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source= myserver;Initial 
Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select 100"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $SqlCmd
$Dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
write-output $DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset) | Out-Null
$Output = $DataSet.Tables
$Output
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source= myserver;Initial 
Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select 100"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.Open()
$Output = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
$Output
```

`$SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()` returns a scalar value. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Definitely the way to go with a single value coming back.

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for. It works but for some reason, It returns two values instead of one. Do you have any ideas on why is that?

Comment: Have you executed it as is? If not, please share your code.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.